# error: unreported exception JSONException in Android

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

So basically what I did is that I created a map inside my class `FlagReportStamped` and iterate it through the keys by `map.keyset` and now I'm having this kind of ERROR

> error: unreported exception JSONException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Can anyone help me refactor my code I'm just a beginner here.

**Activity class:**

```
      //flagreport
      final Call<FlagReportStamped> callFlagReport = jsonAPI.getReportID();
      callFlagReport.enqueue(new Callback<FlagReportStamped>() {
          @Override
          public void onResponse(Call<FlagReportStamped> call, Response<FlagReportStamped> response) {

              if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                  Log.e("mainAction", "Code: " + response.code());
                  return;
              }


              JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response.body().getFlagReport().getMap());
              Iterator<?> keys = jObject.keys();

              while( keys.hasNext() ){
                  String key = (String)keys.next();
                  boolean value = jObject.getBoolean(key); // I get an error here
                  SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(key);//text to change color
                  ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(value ? Color.BLUE: Color.RED), 0, ss.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                  flagName.append(ss);
              }

          }

          @Override
          public void onFailure(Call<FlagReportStamped> call, Throwable t) {
              call.cancel();
          }
      });
  }
```

Basically what I'm trying to do here is to display only the object names from my `json` and instead of displaying their values/status also I iterate it to their object name only and change its color depending on their values/status.

Comment: As per the error I feel you are missing try catch, surround your code with try/catch block and check if you still see the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem at below line because may be you response string not in json object format. that's why you forced to throw json exception

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response.body().getFlagReport().getMap());
```

so cover your parsing snippet with `try` block

```
try{
       JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response.body().getFlagReport().getMap());
            Iterator<?> keys = jObject.keys();
        while( keys.hasNext() ){
            String key = (String)keys.next();
            boolean value = jObject.getBoolean(key); // I get an error here
            SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(key);//text to change color
            ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(value ? Color.BLUE: Color.RED), 0, ss.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
            flagName.append(ss);
        }
    }catch(JSONException e){
       e.printStacktrace();
    }
```